# How can I create new styles for pen, borland in VCL?

Tags: vcl

How can I create new styles for pen, borland in VCL?

```
 LOGPEN LogPen;
    LogPen.lopnStyle = psDash;
    LogPen.lopnWidth = Point(1,1);
    LogPen.lopnColor = RGB(235, 115, 5);
    SelectObject(Form1->Image1->Canvas->Handle, CreatePenIndirect(&LogPen));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `TPen` properties instead of calling `SelectObject()` directly:

```
TPen *Pen = Form1->Image1->Canvas->Pen;
Pen->Style = psDash;
Pen->Width = 1;
Pen->Color = (TColor) RGB(235, 115, 5);
```

`TPen::Style` supports a range of different values:

```
psSolid, psDash, psDot, psDashDot, psDashDotDot, psClear, psInsideFrame, psUserStyle, psAlternate
```

The closest you can get to *creating new styles* for a pen is to use [`ExtCreatePen()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162705.aspx) to create an `HPEN` handle from custom style data, and then assign that to the `TPen::Handle` property.